# Semantics of local PROGMEM

Tags: c++

I want to create a class to better use strings in flash. At its core is the following

```
template<size_t N>
struct progstr
{
    constexpr progstr(const char (&str)[N])
        : progstr(str, make_index_sequence<N> {}) {}

    template<size_t... Is>
    constexpr progstr(const char (&str)[N], index_sequence<Is...>)
        : _str{str[Is]...} {}

    constexpr operator const char*() const {
        return _str;
    }

    const char _str[N] PROGMEM;
};
```

Where `make_index_sequence` and `index_sequence` are [the same](https://godbolt.org/g/41bkiQ) as those from `<utility>`.

The problem arises when I try to emulate `PSTR`

```
template<size_t N>
constexpr const char* pstr(const char (&str)[N])
{
    return progstr<N>{str};  // huh?
}
```

It even compiles. However

- The returned pointer is "dangling", but it is pointing into flash memory. Will this work?
- A `constexpr` function may be called with an array with runtime values, and that cannot possibly create the string in flash can it?

Comment: the `operator` keyword is missing in () operator

Answer (score 2):

I tested with 100 chars string

const char*

```
Sketch uses 1566 bytes
Global variables use 288 bytes
```

with F macro

```
Sketch uses 1594 bytes
Global variables use 188 bytes
```

progstr <101> ps(...

```
Sketch uses 1618 bytes 
Global variables use 288 bytes
```

const char* ps = pstr("...

```
Sketch uses 1502 bytes 
Global variables use 188 bytes
```

the pstr version string has errors at the end, when printed.

**sorry, the pstr function works only if previous sketch version put the string into flash memory. it is not in hex file.**